# Enter an integer and use jump factorial

Tags: java, if-statement

I have tried everything I can think of but nothing is working for this problem...

Prompt the user to enter an integer n.

- If `n` is odd, then compute the following jump-factorial: `1*3*5*7*…*n`;
- If `n` is even, compute the following jump-factorial: `2*4*6*…*n`;
- if `n` is negative or zero, the result is `0`.

Finally, output the result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class problem10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // part 1: open scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // part 2: prompt user to enter a number
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        double num = sc.nextDouble();

        // part 3: tell whether number is odd or even
        for (int i=0; i>0; i+=2) {
            if(i%2);
        }
    }
}
```

That's all I have, but I don't know what to do to tell if the number is even because I can't use integer or double with boolean.

Comment: this must be the homework of the day somewhere

Comment: The condition of the if **must** evaluate to a boolean (true or false). A modulo returns a number. A number is not a boolean

Comment: How do you calculate the factorial of `7.3`? Or asked another way: Why is `num` a `double`?

Comment: Why are you doing a `for` loop here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: That for loop will run forever.

Comment: As a "math major", you should know that `2 * 4 * 6 * ...  * n` is the same as `n * ... * 6 * 4 * 2`, so why don't you just count down from `n` in steps of 2? That way you don't need to test for odd vs even. Oh yeah, and remember to multiply into your result value as you count down, you know: `result = result * x`, or `result *= x` for the short version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO isn't a "do my homework for me" site.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the use of the `modulo` operator:

`i % 2` will give you the reminder of the division of `i / 2`:

If `i` is `5` and you divide it by `2`, the modulo will be `1`, so, there are two options here:

1. Know wether the number is even or odd by comparing the reminder against other value

   - Even numbers have a reminder of 0
   - Odd numbers don't

   Translate that to Java
2. As stated above by @Andreas, you don't need to know if they're even or odd, you can do it this way:

   Count from N to (the nearest number to 0 (i.e. 1 or 2 depending if N is even or odd))

   ```
   if (n > 0) { /*Do whatever you need to do here*/ }
   ```

   `if N <= 0` then return 0

That's all

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem10 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// part 1: open scanner
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// part 2: prompt user to enter a number

System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

int res = 1;

int num = sc.nextInt();

// part 3: tell whether number is odd or even

if(num <= 0) { // if number is negative or 0

    res = 0;
    System.out.println(""+res);
    return;
}

if(num % 2 == 0) { // check for even 

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i+=2) {
        res *= i;
    }

     System.out.println(""+res);
    return;

}else{ // check for odd
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        res *= i;
    }

     System.out.println(""+res);
    return;

}

}

}
```

I have edited the code to make it work.

The problems with your code were:

1. You haven't checked whether number is even or odd or zero
2. For loop in your code was unnecessary..!!

**I want to recommend you to analyze this solution and understand the mistakes you have made and correct them. I also recommend you to understand more about loops and condition checking by following some online tutorials and coding sites.!!**

Hope this help you.!!

Comment: Please don't give them the fish, teach them how to fish instead

Comment: I have shown him what he was doing wrong and how to do it properly.. I think talking about something to someone who have nearly 0 experience in something is not beneficial for him.

Comment: Hope he learns what his mistakes were and how to correct them from the answer I have provided

Comment: Problem 3: Number was a `double`, as this is a homework question I wouldn't give a detailed answer since OP's more than probably will delete his / her question, so that his / her teacher don't find it and know he took the code solution from here

Comment: Learning from this or cheating is his / her choice.!